# NumberInput parse as number

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

My custom dataprovider gets values from number inputs as 
 type string but I need it to be a number.
is it possible with NumberInput to parse it as number?

I alse tried a custom NumberInput but it seems that parse isn't called :/

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import React from "react";
import { Labeled } from 'react-admin';

import { Field } from 'redux-form';

const renderNumberInput = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (

  <TextField
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  >
  </TextField>
);
const parseAsNumber = (value) => (value == null) ? null : Number(value);
const NumberInput = ({ source }) => <Field name={source} component={renderNumberInput} parse={parseAsNumber} label={source}/>
export default NumberInput;
```

also the custom input doesn't have the same look as react admins default one... does anyone know why?

Comment: the parse function looks correct. Are you sure in your redux store that value is a string and not a number?

Comment: in my dataProvider `convertDataRequestToHTTP`  I received a string. There I manually converted it like `parseAsNumber(params.data.latitude);`